# what are those numbers in php serialize output

Tags: php, class, object, serialization, numbers

```
class Aclas {

    private $v = 1;
    private $z;
    protected $y;
    public $xy;
}

$obja = new Aclas;
echo serialize( $obja );
```

I get the output as follows

```
O:5:"Aclas":4:{s:8:"Aclasv";i:1;s:8:"Aclasz";N;s:4:"*y";N;s:2:"xy";N;}
```

but someone please tell me what is `s:8` immediately after opening curly brace.

Comment: `s` means the value is a string and `8` is the length of that string.

Comment: but there I got only six characters s:8:"Aclasv";

Comment: Being its a private member, it will append the class name in the serialized output. I suspect there may be some unprintable characters also included.

Comment: yes thats what happens, it adds Aclas - class name for private member and * for protected, but the string length is 2 numbers higher for private and protected, but not for public, so what is stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{s:8:"Aclasv",` is string, length 8.

I am looking for documentation one sec.

**UPDATE:**
Not seeming to find any documentation on it.  Maybe I'll look to link corresp. PHP source code...  I am curious now too.  Might just be easier to reverse engineer and make sense of it.

**Best Link**
This is pretty cool, code has full parser: https://github.com/ktomk/Serialized

> Serialized is a set of classes that can parse serialized data into a normalized
>   representation (semi structured data or S-expression).

Comment: but there I got only six characters s:8:"Aclasv"; I hope that is class name Aclas and variable v

Comment: similarly s:4:"*y" but there is only 2 chars

Comment: but here it is only 2 s:2:"xy"

Comment: From the docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php  _Object's private members have the class name prepended to the member name; protected members have a '*' prepended to the member name. These prepended values have null bytes on either side._

Comment: so those 2 extra null bytes were counted with string length

Comment: You learn something new every day! I for one, never knew about the null bytes until looking into it.

Comment: What about the O:5 at the very beggining of the serialization? What that stands for?

Answer (score -1):

First of all this question does not make any special sense because:

- serialize generates a storable representation of a value that is ment to use by unserialize only!
- Its output is not 'standardized'. It is not JSON. You are not guaranteed that serializing something in one version of PHP and trying to unserialize() in different version will work.
- Trying to understand and decode characters it generates is pointless.

But if you still want to know:

s:8 means string of 8 bytes.
It is not matching length of "Aclasv" because most probably it contains some unprintable/special characters (null as pointed in other comment to be precise).
please check out this code:

```
class A {
    private $v = 1;
}

$obja = new A;

var_dump($obja);
// object(A)#1 (1) { ["v:private"]=> int(1) }

$x = serialize( $obja );
var_dump($x);
// note that this string is 27 chars long but only 25 are printed!
// string(27) "O:1:"A":1:{s:4:"Av";i:1;}"

var_dump(unserialize($x));
// object(A)#2 (1) { ["v:private"]=> int(1) }

// proof it is not the same:
var_dump(unserialize('O:1:"A":1:{s:4:"Av";i:1;}'));
// bool(false)
```